# integration with respect to signed measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a signed measure. For positive $\mu$, we know that

$$\left|\int f \, d\mu \right|\leq \int| f| \, d\mu$$

Is this still true if we drop the positivity assumption?

Comment: signed, not singed.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: I can imagine a situation where the measures are singed

Comment: A high-temperature expansion?

Answer (score 1):

No, $\left| \int f \; d\mu \right| \le \int |f|\; d|\mu|$.

Comment: but $\mu$ is always positive no ?

Comment: @idm no, the op was asking if the inequality holds for signed measures like it does when the measure is positive, $\mu$ is only assumed to be a signed measure.

Answer (score 0):

As Robert mentioned in his answer, it does not hold in general. In fact, you can easily construct a counterexample even with positive $f$. Take $\Omega = [0,1]$, $f = 1$ and $\mu = -\lambda$ where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure. In that case $|\int f\,\mathrm d\mu| = 1$ but $\int |f|\,\mathrm d\mu = -1$. That's why to compensate positive negativity of $\mu$ we need to take its absolute variation in the RHS.